# Windows refuses to create folder or file when a file respective folder with the same name exists

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, extract

I have tried this on two computers so far. If puzzles me because i can't understand what is going on here

To see it yourself download this file https://pypi.python.org/packages/bd/cf/f0471d8d32b716671be425213403a87b2733f6cf407633d6a6d4db499d6e/Exscript-2.2.tar.gz#md5=33161f0eac2db8791135ac83f910fce1 and try to extract the files

This is happening in Windows 10 and Windows 7
I have tried to extract the files on Linux and it worked. Trying to transfer the files from Linux to my Windows machines fails too

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

Update: the file system is NTFS

Comment: I was unable to reproduce on either my Windows 10 VM or my Windows 7 VM

Comment: Just guessing here: What's the filesystem on the disk you are trying to extract to? I've not looked at your problem zip file, but on, for instance, a FAT32 partition, Windows has issues with multiple items with the same name, differing only in case. Should work on NTFS just fine though.

Comment: the file systems are NTFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what it was but I asked the developer of that package to look at it and he pushed up a new release and this thing is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You are probably transferring those files using a USB drive ?

These drives generally use the older FAT file system that is not case sensitive and folder and a regular file can't have the same name.

Looking at your archive file - directory "Exscript" and file "exscript" are considered to be the same by FAT's standards.

Comment: Yes that has something to do with the problem. That is the first error that I get when I try to transfer the files from Linux to Windows.

Comment: The file exscript and the folder Exscript seem to generate a conflict here. i just tried the same on my colleague's computer